# Installing Ceiling Fan with light to outdoor porch

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I recently had a home built and asked the builder to leave three ceiling boxes in my covered deck for future ceiling fans.

The picture attached is what was installed.  There are two white (capped), two black (capped), two reds (not capped) and a ground.  Each mount has one switch.

I purchased a fan with light that has one white, blue, black, and ground.  I connected the whites together, the blacks together in addition to the blue.  Nothing happened.  I took the blue out of the black pigtail and connected it to the red wires and nothing happen.

Where did I go wrong?

[image]

Comment: Did you test the wires before you started hooking them up  to see if they had power and what ones did have power and what ones were switched? What do the  fixture instructions say about how to wire it?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inisde of the switch box that controls this location?